# Examples for Algorithms that can be used for Stock Market Analysis

Tags: algorithm, stocks, stockquotes

I was working on a Stock Market Analysis website as a college project.

I was keen on knowing some algorithms which I could potentially use for analysing trends in the stock market.

I would be glad if some one could help.

Comment: maybe this would be better on http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This question would probably be better posed on [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/), the statistics site.

Comment: The discussion surrounding this question may be of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1989992/predict-stock-market-values

Answer (score 1):

My Calc professor used to work for a firm that did this. It can't be reliably done, or else wealthy people would do it until it would cease to work, but you can get better than random guessing hopefully. My prof mentioned looking at stocks that had a negative first derivative, but positive second derivative. There are two distributed computing stock predictors that you could look at to see how they work, **MoneyBee** and **Gstock**.

Answer (score 0):

The **moving average** can be used to show general trends over a period of time.